# Error: network 'Scenario' not found

Tags: veins

I have installed veins-4.5 and I can run the Erlangen example.
However, when I try to run the example in the subprojects/veins_inet folder it gives "Error: Network 'Scenario' not found, check .ini and .ned files"
However the Scenario.ned is in the same folder as omnetp.ini.
How do I solve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: Did you import the folder as a second project "veins_inet" or are you running the simulation from the normal "veins" project?

Comment: I am using the subproject veins_inet that comes with veins-4.5.

Comment: I am using the subproject veins_inet that comes with veins-4.5. It is installed in the omnet IDE. I have previously installed veins_inet as a second project, but it gives the exactly the same error.

Comment: Solved! It is required to do manually "make" inside the subprojects/veins_inet folder. Building the project with IDE was not doing this make in my case.

Comment: Importing veins_inet as a second project is the recommended way and should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the interface graphic, do it: click in subprojects/veins_inet and next in omnet ++ project -> build all.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for that error is that the .ini isn't correct.
In particular, if you wish to simulate using Gui (Tkenv), your .ini file should include something like:

```
[Config MyNetwork]
```

However, for a command-line simulation (Cmdenv), the .ini file should read instead:

```
cmdenv-config-name = MyNetwork
```

in the latter case, you should also add "-u Cmdenv" to your run command.
Confusing between the 2 options above raises the error ""Error: Network '...' not found, check .ini and .ned files".